# Getting SugarSync to mount homebrewed osxfuse

Tags: installation, homebrew, fuse, sugarsync

I'm trying to get SugarSync v2.46 running on OS 10.6.8.  I also use Homebrew to manage install packages.  After I installed SugarSync, I came to discover that it installed osxfuse 2.6.1 on my system, which leads to a slew of warnings as identified by `brew doctor` as this installed files to `/usr/local`.  I figured the best way to get rid of these warnings was to uninstall Fuse, done in the System Preferences pane, and then reinstall using `brew install osxfuse`.  As per the caveat, I also directly wrote certain bundles to the proper locations via

```
sudo /bin/cp -RfX /usr/local/opt/osxfuse/Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs /Library/Filesystems/
sudo /bin/cp -RfX /usr/local/opt/osxfuse/Library/Frameworks/OSXFUSE.framework /Library/Frameworks/
sudo chmod +s /Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/Support/load_osxfusefs
```

Based on the osxfuse Wiki this has basically achieved a complete install of osxfuse 2.7.1.  I only lack the icon in System Preferences.  Nevertheless, SugarSync doens't recognize this, and insists on installing its prepackaged Fuse.

I have the bundles in the right locations, and I can load the kernel extension.  The libraries are all in the right spots (though they are symlinked to the brew Cellar).  I contacted SugarSync for information on how their app checks for a pre-existing version of Fuse but was told to upgrade to their version 3 which I can't do right now.

Have I missed something important that will prevent apps from mounting the kernel extension?  Or is this a SugarSync specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional detective work I finally figured this out.

Turns out that the v2 release channel of SugarSync doesn't use the OS X Fuse kernel extension, but the totally defunct MacFUSE extension.  The osxfuse 2.6.1 install package is bundled with SugarSync.app so that it can always install the MacFUSE compatibility layer option if necessary.  Homebrew, on the other hand, [skips that install option when installing osxfuse, and does not provide an install option for it](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/114) -- and rightfully so; MacFUSE is dead and really should stay that way (and to SugarSync's credit, version 3 did dispense with it).

In the meantime, however, the zombie must live on in my OS.  After running `brew uninstall osxfuse`, I used the official package (from https://osxfuse.github.io) to install osxfuse *with the compatibility layer option selected*.  This does install libraries to /usr/local/lib, but homebrew isn't coughing up any conflicts when `brew doctor` is run...not yet anyway.